# Sitecore Publishing Restriction Override

Tags: sitecore, publishing

I have two publishing target - one is stage and one is production.The publishing on Production should adhere to the publishing restrictions, but publishing on Stage should not look at or discard the valid to and valid from dates and publish under any circumstance.

I have written a publishing pipeline (PipelinePublishProvider). I am not sure how could I manage to overwrite the field values temporarily so it publishes on to stage every-time.

```
public class StagePublishOverride : PipelinePublishProvider
{

    public override PublishHelper CreatePublishHelper(PublishOptions options)
    {

        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(options, "options");

        if (options.TargetDatabase.Name.ToLower() == "stage")
        {
            Item itemToBePublished = new Item(options.RootItem.ID, options.RootItem.InnerData, new Database("web"));
            itemToBePublished.Editing.BeginEdit();                
            itemToBePublished.Publishing.ValidTo = DateTime.MaxValue;
            itemToBePublished.Publishing.ValidFrom = DateTime.MinValue;
            itemToBePublished.Editing.EndEdit();
            options.RootItem = itemToBePublished;
        }

        if (options is ExtendedPublishOptions)

            return new ExtendedPublishHelper(options as ExtendedPublishOptions);

        return new PublishHelper(options);

    }

}

public class ExtendedPublishHelper : PublishHelper
{

    private readonly ExtendedPublishOptions _options;

    public ExtendedPublishHelper(ExtendedPublishOptions options)

        : base(options)
    {

        _options = options;

    }

    public override Item GetVersionToPublish(Item sourceItem)
    {

        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(sourceItem, "sourceItem");

        if (Options is ExtendedPublishOptions)
        {

            return sourceItem.Publishing.GetValidVersion(Options.PublishDate, _options.RequireApproval);

        }

        return sourceItem.Publishing.GetValidVersion(Options.PublishDate, true);

    }

}

public class ExtendedPublishOptions : PublishOptions
{

    public ExtendedPublishOptions(Database sourceDatabase, Database targetDatabase, PublishMode mode, Language language, DateTime publishDate, bool requireApproval)

        : base(sourceDatabase, targetDatabase, mode, language, publishDate)
    {

        RequireApproval = requireApproval;

    }

    public bool RequireApproval { get; set; }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll be better off adding a processor to the `publishItem` pipeline.  Here is some UNTESTED code, which I think will serve your purpose:

```
public class PublishOverride : PublishItemProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)context, "context");
        if (context.Action != PublishAction.None)
            return;
        Item sourceItem = this.GetSourceItem(context);
        if (sourceItem == null)
            return;

        var stagingDB = Factory.GetDatabase("Stage");

        if (stagingDB != null && !sourceItem.Publishing.NeverPublish && context.PublishContext.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase == stagingDB)
        {
            context.Action = PublishAction.PublishVersion;
            context.VersionToPublish = sourceItem;
        }

    }
    private Item GetSourceItem(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)context, "context");
        return context.PublishHelper.GetSourceItem(context.ItemId);
    }
}
```

Make sure you patch it in before the DetermineAction processor in the default config.  So your config patch would look like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <publishItem>
        <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.DetermineAction, Sitecore.Kernel']"
                   type="YourNamespace.PublishOverride, YourAssembly"  />
      </publishItem>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Code updated. Made a change to get the item via the `PublishHelper.GetSourceItem` method.  The previous method, `PublishHelper.GetItemToPublish` actually checks for the publish date, and therefore would not satisfy the request of publishing without restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Amir ! This code did work. Really appreciate your help.